# Make an object the new gravity point

Tags: objects, world

say, I want to make a both sided flat world - plane with things on both sides, having gravity pull them towards it.
Or a spherical world having its own gravitational pull.
Are any of these possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add a force field of type [Force](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/physics/force_fields/types/force.html). Put it to the center in order to create a spherical world having its own gravitational pull. Use shape "Plane" to have a both sided flat world. As the manual says:

> **Shape** The field is either a Point, with omni-directional influence, or a Plane, constant in the XY-plane, changes only in Z direction.
>
> **Strength** The strength of the field effect. This can be positive or negative to change the direction that the force operates in. A force field’s strength is scaled with the force object’s scale, allowing you to scale up and down scene, keeping the same effects.